# Meaning $mod.$ and differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

What do you means the following?
For example $dw_1 \equiv 0$ mod. [$w_1,w_2,$ ].

Thank you

Comment: Where have you seen it?

Comment: For example here https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/hyperex1.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjf5sO4lMjUAhUEY1AKHW84BAMQFggxMAU&usg=AFQjCNHMkYHEiydDZt3FXhFNssS5B2-BPQ&sig2=GRmmW0pRPCkp8Ad4l5-Wcw

Comment: They have a quotient space $\Omega^2(M)/\{I\}$ so I assume that $\alpha = \beta \pmod \theta$ means that $\alpha - \beta = \iota \theta$ for some $\iota \in \{I\}$. Hopefully someone else can clarify.